# How to show a login view in SwiftUI when the app return to a backgrounded app after a few minutes?

Tags: ios, swiftui

After working with `UIKit` for several years I am now having a hard time working with `SwiftUI` for the first time.

To get started I am trying to create the following basic app setup:

- When the launches a login screen is displayed requesting a PIN code
- When the app resigns active / enters background its content should be hidden by a lock screen.
- When returning to the within a minute, no login is required
- When returning to the app after more than one minute, the login screen is shown again

In order to check whether a login is required or not when returning to the app, I need to know how much time has passed since the app was backgrounded. Thus I need to store the backgrounding date somehow. **What is the corret way to do this in SwiftUI?**

---

**Code:**

```
struct AppContainerView: View {
    @State private var isInBackground = false
    
    //private var didEnterBackgroundDate: Date?          // Version 1
    //@State private var didEnterBackgroundDate = Date?  // Version 2

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MainView()
            
            if isInBackground {
                LockScreenView()
            } else {
                let secondsInBackground = (didEnterBackgroundDate != nil ? Date().timeIntervalSince(didEnterBackgroundDate!) : -1)

                if secondsInBackground < 0 || secondsInBackground > 60 {
                    // Request login on launch (secondsInBackground == -1) and when
                    // returning to app after more then 60 seconds
                    LoginScreenView()
                }
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
            didEnterBackgroundDate = Date()
            isInBackground = true
        }
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
            isInBackground = false
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

Using a `@State` variable to save and handle `isInBackground` seems to be the right choice, since this really defines a **state** of the UI: The lock screens should only be visible when the UI is in "background" state. Additionally the UI needs to be updated when this state changes.

The backgrounding date however is not an actual state, is it? It is just a value which is needed to decide how to proceed when the state `isInBackground` changes to `false`. Additionally no UI update is required when the backgrounding date is set / changes.

So, my first try (`Version 1`) was using a simple `private var` to store `didEnterBackgroundDate`. However, this brings up an `Cannot assign to  property: 'self' is immutable` error when setting the date within the `willResignActiveNotification` handler.

My second try (`Version 2`) was to define it as `@State`. **While this works just fine and as intended**, it somehow feels wrong. **Is this really the correct solution since this is not an actual state as described above?**

- Am I putting too much emphasis on the term "Status"? Is this just a keyword which should be used for all mutable values, no matter if they really represent a "status"?
- Or am I getting it wrong it wrong and such things should be handled in a totally different way?

Comment: The short answer is you don't do this directly in SwiftUI. SwiftUI is just views. You need some model that can track your app's state and expose this via `@Published` properties. Your SwiftUI view hierarchy can react to changes in these properties.

Comment: Using State would be one way to do it. I would create a separate class (a viewmodel or a manager whatever you want to call it) and create a Published property as Paulw11 said above. You can create an instance of this class in your main view and track the Published property like you're tracking your @State, as this is a more common practice.